# Domino XPages: Import PKCS12-SSL-Certificate into ID from ID-Vault

Tags: ssl, xpages, lotus-domino, pkcs#12

IBM introduced the dominoIDVaultBean in Xpages. Is it possible to get the ID from ID Vault, add an PKCS12-SSL-Certificate and Upload the ID to the Vault again with pure XPages and no API?

With API this is possible via:

- SECidfGet
- PKCS12_ImportFileToIDFile
- SECidfPut

Comment: What did you try with the bean so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually that is quite an easy task if you use Domino 9.0.1 FP8. I solved the issue using the newly introduced IDVault class as well as calling the PKCS12_ImportFileToIDFile C API via JNI.

So basically your code (in a bean initiated by a REST call) could look like this:

```
        Session session = DominoUtils.getCurrentSession();
        IDVault idvault = session.getIDVault();

        //****** DOWNLOAD ID *****************
        idvault.getUserIDFile(this.getIdFilePath(), this.getUsername(), this.getIdPassword(), VAULT_SERVER);

        //****** IMPORT P12 ******************
        Native.setProtected(true);
        nnotes lib = (nnotes) Native.loadLibrary(NOTES_LIB, nnotes.class);
        short errorint = lib.PKCS12_ImportFileToIDFile(this.getP12Path(), this.getP12Pin(), this.getIdFilePath(), this.getIdPassword(), 0, 0, 0);

        //****** SYNC ID BACK TO VAULT *******
        idvault.syncUserIDFile(this.getIdFilePath(), this.getUsername(),this.getIdPassword(), VAULT_SERVER);
```

To call the C API via java this is a good [reference](http://nevermind.dk/nevermind/blog.nsf/subject/calling-the-domino-c-api-from-an-xpage-or-a-java-agent) to start with.